# how to implement pagination with sinatra?

Tags: ruby, pagination, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra and Ruby 1.9.3.

I have a list of items and want to paginate them. I'm new to web development so I don't know how to do that in detail.

I don't know how to implement the links for each page, such as the link to `page2` on `page1`. Should I do it like so:

```
<a href='?page=2'
```

I don't think that's a good idea because it would overwrite my other parameters like `?searchterm=` and `?sort=?` and it wouldn't take the existing `?page=` parameters into account.

My idea was to use the same form as my `searchterm` etc., and change the value via buttons and JavaScript. But, that seems to be quite complicated and all big websites, including stackoverflow.com, use links for their pagination.

How do I achieve pagination which features the following:

1. Include other parameters when going to another page.
2. Overwrite the existing `?page=` parameter.
3. No Javascript (optional, but would be good).

Comment: This isn't an easy question to answer because we don't know enough about your system. Do you have a huge dataset in a database or a small set in code or a file? What sort of response time do you have between your DB and your HTML/Sinatra host? Do you want the browser and user to have access to all the data at once or a small amount?

Comment: you're right, the question wasn't perfect :/

Comment: It's one of those things you'll encounter time and again in different languages and app-front-ends and with different data. I've handled pagination in my DB queries, and in JavaScript. It just depended on whether I wanted to avoid dumping several thousand rows to a browser or make the user suffer.

Comment: I need to save bandwith and I also need to group the items by created at. I request all items which match the searchtern and then I sort it in my controller. I need to save bandwith!

Comment: Then any answer needs to paginate in the database, which is easy using `limit` and maybe `offset`, depending on the DBM. Group and sort in your SQL query because the DBM is optimized for it. You don't say what you use for your DB connection for an ORM, but they all support that stuff.

Comment: thank you! `OFFSET` is a good idea ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always load the necessary parameters into instance vars:

```
@page = params[:page] || 1
```

and then use it as you were doing:

```
<a href="?page=#{@page + 1}&search_term=#{params[:searchterm]}"...
```

Comment: thank you very much, why didn't I get that I can use the params[] hash? :D

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, adding a little to @ChuckE's answer:

```
# Controller
  def index
    # ...
    @models = MyModel.find(:yourquery)
    if params[:page]
      page = params[:page].to_i
      @models = @models[(page * 10)..(page + 10)] # Selecting an slice out of the @models array
    end
  end

# In your view
  - @model.each do |item|
    =# do stuff
  = link_to "Next Page", "?page=#{@page + 1}"
  = link_to "Next Page", "?page=#{@page - 1}" unless @page = 1
```

Comment: thanks, but the first answer covers point 1, keep the existing parameters ;)

Comment: `[(page * 10)..(page + 10)]` part seems incorrect. `page = 1` gives `[10..11]`, `page = 2` - `[20..12]`

Answer (score 1):

There's also a popular gem called `will_paginate` which does some of this stuff automatically for you: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate. Works with Sinatra.

```
## Sinatra app:
require 'will_paginate'
require 'will_paginate/active_record'  # or data_mapper/sequel
```